# Apperance of no-break space character in typing

Tags: macos

Using TeXShop to typeset LaTeX, I often come across the error `Package inputenc error: Character \u8 not set up for use with LaTeX`. That, I have learnt, is due to the fact that, for some reason, some spaces become "no-break space"s (U+00A0), which apparently `inputenc` doesn't like. *So this is NOT a LaTeX question, but just one that was brought up by LaTeX. It might be about TeXShop or about I don't know what, but the LaTeX part is definitely solved.* So the question is: why does it turn up? Is it a shortcut I am unaware of (I'm om Mac OS X 10.7.5), a TeXShop specific thing, or something else?
PS I'm not sure if the tag is appropriate. Were I not forced to give at least one, I probably would have given none. *LaTeX, as stated above, is definitely NOT an appropriate tag for this question. The one I had put was probably more appropriate. Anyway I'll have a look at the list of popular tags (if I find one) and change the tag to the one that seems most appropriate to me.*

Comment: I don't think the latex tag is appropriate. My question is NOT about LaTeX, otherwise I would have asked it on TeX-LaTeX SX, not here. The closest it can be to TeX-related, as far as I can tell, is that this happens in TeXShop, a text editor designed for LaTeX. Do not be misled by the introducing part quoting a LaTeX error: it's _just_ an _introduction_.

Comment: Anybody got any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Wikipedia states on [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), Alt+Space on Mac inputs the No-Break Space. In speedy typing, I probably inadvertently press Alt while typing the space, resulting in this problem.